# Flip animation for Cards in RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, viewflipper

Am having a horizontal recycler view of 5 cards, On click on each card i have to flip that card and show new card in that clicked card position, How do i do this.?

I had tried with ViewFlipper, But no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution is to use this library : [EasyFlipView](https://github.com/wajahatkarim3/EasyFlipView)

Short example of how to use it in RecycleView :

Use this .xml layout as Adapter view item.
Pay attention to adding back side layout (back side of card to flip) as first after `EasyFlipView`, because it is the way this library recognize which layout will be Front or Back.

```xml
<com.wajahatkarim3.easyflipview.EasyFlipView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/flipView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:flipDuration="400"
    app:flipEnabled="true"
    app:flipType="horizontal"
    app:flipOnTouch="false">
    <!--Back-->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/backSide"
        layout="@layout/back_activity" />

    <!--Front-->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/frontSide"
        layout="@layout/front_activity" />

</com.wajahatkarim3.easyflipview.EasyFlipView>
```

After in your `CustomRecycleViewAdapter` where you will bind your view.
Set `ClickListener` for backSide and frontSide with body to flip the card as shown bellow (example in Kotlin) :

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(data[position])
}

inner class ViewHolder(private val view: View) : 
       RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
 private val backSide: ConstraintLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.backSide)
 private val frontSide: ConstraintLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.frontSide)
 private val flipView: EasyFlipView = view.findViewById(R.id.flipView)

 init{
  backSide.setOnClickListener {
            flipView.flipDuration = 1000
            flipView.flipTheView()
        }
   frontSide.setOnClickListener {
            flipView.flipDuration = 1000
            flipView.flipTheView()
        }
 }
 fun bind(item: SomeData) {//.... }

}
```

All credit to author of this library, link - https://github.com/wajahatkarim3/EasyFlipView

Comment: View is refreshing when animation ends

Comment: This library does not give a 3D effects. I found one link from Google Developer account but sadly it works for fragments only.  https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/animation/cardflip.html